# oracle Report Builder - Using Case in a query produces symbol?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle Report builder and I've noticed when I use the case function

```
Case Column 
  when this then that 
  when this then that 
  else this 
end
```

in a query it produces this symbol-
[Symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCP9j.png)
. This causes issues with the final output where duplicates occur.
Any feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: first - check, if you gave an alias to the column, in which you used case. second, the sql/plsql engine of Report Builder works a bit differently from SQL engine of your database. What works perfectly fine as a query in your sql tool, might not work in report builder, its an old tool. It used to happen for certain reports on which I used to work as well. There are certain syntax which you cannot use in sql query in report builder. My suggestion is to create a formula column and use your case statement there.

Comment: I don;t have access to `Report Builder` so I can't give you a test case right now, I am only suggesting this based on my past working experience. You may choose to not believe me :)

Comment: Many thanks for the feedback, I'll take it on board :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking about an icon which looks like a "C/D", next to query name, right? If so, it represents a **non-linkable query**.

Documentation ([2.3.5 About non-linkable queries](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/bi.1111/b32122/orbr_concepts2003.htm#RSBDR337)) says:

> A non-linkable query is a detail query that contains column objects
>   that prevent the query from being linked to via a column-to-column
>   link (when you create a column-to-column link, Reports Builder adds a
>   WHERE clause to your query). If you attempt to create such a link, a
>   message dialog box displays, which prompts you to choose whether to
>   create a group-to-group query (using the parent groups), or to cancel
>   the operation. A non-linkable query displays a non-linkable icon in
>   its title bar (C/D).
>
> Instead, you can create a group-to-group link (when you create a
>   group-to-group link, Reports Builder does not add a WHERE clause to
>   your query) between the two queries and add a WHERE clause to the
>   child query’s SELECT statement, using a bind variable to reference the
>   parent column.
>
> For example, suppose you want to create a column-to-column link
>   between the ADDRESS.STREET column in your child query and the LOC1
>   column in your parent query. You can create a group-to-group link, and
>   then modify the child query SQL statement to say: SELECT * FROM EMP E
>   WHERE E.ADDRESS.STREET = :LOC1

I'm not sure it is related to your problems with "duplicates". The simplest way to get rid of them is to use DISTINCT keyword, e.g. `select distinct this, that from ...` but the actual solution might differ, depending on what you really have & do.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have noticed this tends to occur whenever I use case, When I use decode instead it seems to remove the non-linkable icon and works. Thank you for the advice. :)